# How to assign char instance of a class

Tags: c++

```
class demoClass {
private:
    char item_name[50];

public:
    void set_item_name(char *item_name){ this->item_name=item_name; };
};
```

I am receiving error :
**invalid assignment of char to char[50]**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't assign strings like that. You have several options:

```
class demoClass{
private:
    char *item_name;

public:

    void set_item_name(char *item_name){
        this->item_name = item_name;
    };
};
```

or

```
class demoClass{
private:
    char item_name[50];


public:

    void set_item_name(char *item_name){
        strcpy(this->item_name,item_name);
    };
};
```

or

```
class demoClass{
private:
    string item_name;


public:

    void set_item_name(char *item_name){
        this->item_name = item_name;
    };
};
```

Be aware that the first two of these have "gotchas" if you aren't careful.

**In the first one**, if the life of the pointer you pass ends before the object is destroyed. You'll get a dangling pointer.

**In the second one**, if your string is longer than 49 characters, you'll overrun the array.

**The third one** is the preferred C++ way.

Comment: Use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`

Comment: And then set the last character of the array to `\0`.

Comment: Or even better, write yourself an equivalent of BSD `strlcpy`. For 50 characters, though, `strncpy` will do.

Comment: Concerning the 'gotchas': Just use #3 unless you know what you're doing. If you use #2, use strncpy instead of strcpy, as suggested by Seth Carnegie below, to prevent a buffer overrun.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign a pointer to an array. You really want to copy the string that is pointed to by the `char*` to your array:

```
void set_item_name(char *item_name){
    strncpy(this->item_name, item_name, 50);
    this->item_name[49] = 0; // because if the string is longer than 50, it won't be NULL terminated
};
```

If you don't want to keep a copy of it and just want to retain a pointer to it (and you trust that that memory won't be deallocated, you can just store the pointer by changing `item_name` to a `char*` and keeping everything else like it was in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and pointer are not same:

Try:

```
void set_item_name(char item_name[]){strcpy(this->item_name,item_name);};
```